# Can I wait for my component to be connected for react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

How can I wait for react-redux to return my new connected component? Basically, I have an index screen where I make a query to a database to save the clients, the response of that api call is the argument with which I want to trigger my SAVE_CUSTOMERS action and then make a map in the view.

This error is because the object as such that I want to make the map does not yet exist, and this is why I forge a wait for that Hash and if it works.

I have several ways to force this to work, but I'm here for a fancy solution

**customers.js**

```
import React from "react";
import bridge from "../../helpers/bridge/index";
import { save_customers } from "../../../actions/customers";
import CustomersUI from "../../components/Customers/CustomersUI";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class CustomersScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    bridge
      .getCustomers(this.props.user.access_token)
      .then((customers) => this.props.save_customers(customers))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CustomersUI
        customers={this.props.customers}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    customers: state.customers,
  }),
  {
    save_customers: save_customers,
  }
)(CustomersScreen);
```

My reducer

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SAVE_CUSTOMERS":
      return action.customers;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And... The action,

```
export function save_customers(customers) {
  return {
    type: "SAVE_CUSTOMERS",
    customers,
  };
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Obviously I have a combineReducers exporting everything.

Perhaps waiting for the component to be connected is not exactly the most fancy way to solve it, it is just the closest idea I have about it. Less than 1 week ago I am in React Native, never used Redux before. Thank you!

Comment: Where does `...props.customers.map...` come from?

Comment: From my UI. Where i do the `.map`. I didn't want to add it so as not to sound redundant. It's something like `props.customer.map((customer)=> (COMPONENT...))`

Answer (score 1):

The `customers` array from your state might be undefined while it is waiting for the response from `getCustomers`. Therefore, on your render method, you should conditionally render the child `CustomersUI` only when `customers` is defined.

```
 render() {
    const { customers } = this.props;
    return (
      customers && (
        <CustomersUI
          customers={this.props.customers}
        />
      )
    );
  }
```

Alternatively, the `CustomersUI` component should handle undefined values, such that it won't throw that error.

Comment: That doesn't look very fancy. Mainly because I can have more than one array to bring from my provider and the user experience can be very affected in that case. The ideal is to render and then update with whatever is required. Besides that, it is not working either 

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't work? Meaning the component does not render at all..? Or..?